# imacros cut a part of txt from extracted html

Tags: javascript, iframe, eval, imacros

I'm creating a macro and I have a problem.

The site changes its iframe name everytime I reload. So I want to grab the iframe name and put it in to a variable. Problem is I don't know how to get the iframe name out of extracted html

```
TAG POS=7 TYPE=iframe ATTR=ID:* EXTRACT=HTM

<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=271750421132&amp;channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F7tUlZKGPU61.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df39559b33f3fe54%26domain%3Dwww.collegehumor.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.collegehumor.com%252Ff2b6c86b5ce5e7%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.collegehumor.com%2Ftoplist%2F6754891%2Fthe-biggest-pet-peeves&amp;locale=en_US&amp;mobile=false&amp;numposts=10&amp;order_by=social&amp;sdk=joey&amp;skin=light&amp;version=v2.0&amp;width=570" class="fb_ltr" title="Facebook Social Plugin" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 2589px; width: 607px; outline: 1px solid blue;" scrolling="no" name="f17c627e8f47218" id="f31982b5a1b9c64"></iframe>
```

I just need to get the iframe id which is `f31982b5a1b9c64`. I've very little knowledge in javascript so I can't seems to figure this out.

Comment: Do you want to get the iframes name attribute or id attribute, and does the id change as well?

Comment: Hi. I need iframe id. Thanks.  Yes id changes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line if you want to grab the iframe name:

```
SET frameName EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/name="(\w*)"/)[1];")
```

or this one to grab the iframe id:

```
SET frameId EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/id="(\w*)"/)[1];")
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much. Frame name works. Thanks again.